# how to add/append multiple string data in DOMDocument xml using php

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

The below is my sample xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
      <book>
         <book NAME="ci_id">
            <PVAL><![CDATA[78965]]></PVAL>
         </book>
         <author>testing</author>
         <title>Md kaif khan</title>
         <genre>kkkk</genre>
         <price>5.95</price>
         <publish_date>2016-09-10</publish_date>
         <description>No...........</description>
      </book>
      <book>
         <book NAME="ci_id">
            <PVAL><![CDATA[78965]]></PVAL>
         </book>
         <author>asdfsaf</author>
         <title>Md asdfsaf khan</title>
         <genre>Age</genre>
         <price>6.95</price>
         <publish_date>2016-09-10</publish_date>
         <description>Asd</description>
      </book>
      <book>
         <book NAME="ci_id">
            <PVAL><![CDATA[5210]]></PVAL>
         </book>
         <author>Test</author>
         <title>Testing second</title>
         <genre>Ttt</genre>
         <price>8.94</price>
         <publish_date>2013-10-15</publish_date>
         <description>Nothing</description>
      </book>
   </catalog>
```

Here my requirement is to add multiple records
i.e,from < book>... < /book> based on id(i.e, CDATA[78965]).

```
<?php
$xmlFileToLoad   =  dirname(__FILE__) .'/testing.xml';
      $xmlFileToSave   =  'testing-modified.xml';

      $cdata_text = '
      <book>
         <book NAME="ci_id">
            <PVAL><![CDATA[78965]]></PVAL>
         </book>
         <author>testing</author>
         <title>First</title>
         <genre>kk</genre>
         <price>5.95</price>
         <publish_date>2016-09-10</publish_date>
         <description>Just i am testing.</description>
      </book>
      <book>
         <book NAME="ci_id">
            <PVAL><![CDATA[78965]]></PVAL>
         </book>
         <author>testing1</author>
         <title>Second</title>
         <genre>kone</genre>
         <price>5.12</price>
         <publish_date>2014-10-20</publish_date>
         <description>i am testing One.</description>
      </book>
      ';

      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $dom->load($xmlFileToLoad);
      $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    function findStopPointByName($xml, $query) {
      $upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAZSCZCÓL";
      $lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazscznól";
      $arg_query    = "translate(text(), '$upper', '$lower')";
      $q = "//book[book/PVAL[contains($arg_query, '$query')]]" ."\n";
      return $xml->query($q);
    }

    foreach(findStopPointByName($xpath,'78965') as $node)
    {
      // Save parent - after removing node we will use it
      $parent = $node->parentNode;
      $parent->removeChild($node);

      // Load XML from text. You cann't append text, only node
      $data = new DOMDocument();
      $data->loadXML($cdata_text);

      // Import all new XML to our one and append to saved parent
      $ndata =  $dom->importNode($data->documentElement, true);   
      $parent->appendChild($ndata); 
    }

    $dom->save($xmlFileToSave);
```

Here in the above code in $cdata_text, when i use single record(< book>..< /book>) is it added correctly in the destination file. But i need to add there two record(which have same id(i.e,78965, actually in my code i am search with the specific id in the xml and updating with the $cdata_text with that, when i use single record it is updating, but now i want to add multiple records which the same id(from the $cdata_text) Or i can say, i need to find the id from the xml file and need to update it with the $cdata_text string.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current source loads a fragment string as a separate document. This will fail because an wellformed XML document can only have a single document element node.

A document fragment is a special node type in DOM, so you can create and append it like any other node. It has a method `appendXml()` to parse the XML fragment string.

Here is a simple example:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml('<catalog/>');

$fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXml(
  '<book><title>First</title></book>
   <book><title>Second</title></book>'
);

$document->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog><book><title>First</title></book>
   <book><title>Second</title></book></catalog>
```

Comment: Hi @ThW, thanks for your help. updated my code    foreach(findStopPointByName($xpath,'78965') as $node)
    { $parent = $node->parentNode; $parent->removeChild($node);
      $document = new DOMDocument(); $document->loadXml('<catalog/>');
      $fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
      $fragment->appendXml($cdata_text);
      $ndata = $document->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);
      $ndata1 =  $dom->importNode($document->documentElement, true);
      $dom->appendChild($ndata1);
    }
    $dom->save($xmlFileToSave); in the above main code. output is not correct

Comment: Hi @ThW, the output contains more catalog nodes, Can you please help me

Comment: You should not load '<catalog/>' inside your function. The fragment replaces the creation and loading of the document inside your function. The first two lines are preparing a document so that the fragment has a target - making the example self contained and working: https://eval.in/627067

Comment: thanks for your reply, as i am new to xml, facing some issue, Can you please take a look on these code. https://eval.in/627261 once again thanks for your great support